# Average speed checks for cars

Tags: python, camera, average

I have a school assessment on average speed checks for cars. So when the car passes one speed camera it starts a timer and when it passes the next speed camera at a given distance it stops the timer. Then it takes the speed it took for the car to drive the given distance and then divide it by the given distance and then it comes out with the average speed of the car. Then we have to decide whether the car is breakage the speed limit or is under the speed limit.

This is what i have so far:

```
from datetime import datetime

start = input("Press enter to start")
starttime =(datetime.now())
stop = input("Press enter to stop")
stoptime =(datetime.now())
dist1 = 0
dist2 = input("enter dist2:")
time = stoptime-starttime
print(time)
distance = int(dist2) - dist1
print(distance)
speed = int(distance)% time
print(speed)
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a code writing service, please show your efforts including existing code, inputs, desired output and any errors

Comment: from datetime import datetime

start = input("Press enter to start")
starttime =(datetime.now())
stop = input("Press enter to stop")
stoptime =(datetime.now())
dist1 = 0
dist2 = input("enter dist2:")
time = stoptime-starttime
print(time)
distance = int(dist2) - dist1
print(distance)
speed = int(distance)% time
print(speed)

Comment: Please edit this into your question and ensure it's formatted as code, posting code in comments is not productive and loses formatting, thanks

Comment: What's the issue you're encountering with your currect code?

Comment: Hints: 1). Use `time.time()` to get the current time in seconds. 2). The division operator is `/`; `%` is modulus. 3). If something's already an integer it's pointless converting it to integer again.

Comment: What's your question ?

Answer (score 2):

You have almost managed to get everything working. As has been mentioned, you will find it easier to work with Python's `time.time()` function which will return you a current value in seconds. You should consider what units you are using and display them to the user, for example is distance in miles, metres or kilometres?

You should be working with `floats` as the time taken will include fractions of a second. When displaying floats, you can tell Python to display the value to a given precision, in this case 2 decimal places.

You were using the Python's `%` (modulus) operator rather than dividing your answer.

```
import time

speed_limit = 30

input("Press enter to start")
start_time = time.time()
input("Press enter to stop")
stop_time = time.time()
distance = float(input("Enter distance: "))
time_taken = stop_time - start_time

print('Time taken: {:.2f} seconds'.format(time_taken))
print('Distance: {:.2f}'.format(distance))
speed = distance / time_taken
print('Speed: {:.2f}'.format(speed))

if speed > speed_limit:
    print("You were breaking the speed limit")
```

For example, this would display the following:

```
Press enter to start
Press enter to stop
Enter distance: 1000
Time taken: 2.52 seconds
Distance: 1000.00
Speed: 396.80
You were breaking the speed limit
```